# Dialog within a dialog: Second dialog not working

Tags: applescript

Im trying to write a script that makes a dialog box ask "Sleep, restart, or Shutdown" with an extra dialog box come up when i select the "Sleep" option.

The restart and shut down work perfectly but when I use the sleep button and the extra dialog pops up, they don't work.

```
set question to display dialog "Sleep, Restart, or Shutdown?" buttons {"Sleep", "Restart", "Shutdown"} with title "What do you want to do?"
set answer to button returned of question

if answer is equal to "Restart" then
    tell application "Finder" to restart
end if

if answer is equal to "Shutdown" then
    tell application "Finder" to shutdown
end if

if answer is equal to "Sleep" then
    display dialog "Exit All and Sleep or Just Sleep?" buttons {"Exit All", "Just Sleep"}
end if

if answer is equal to "Exit All" then
    tell application "Finder" to run application "/Users/kjoesting/Desktop/Exit All and sleep.app"
else if answer is equal to "Just Sleep" then
    tell application "Finder" to sleep
end if
```

The problem is the "Exit all and Sleep or Just Sleep" Neither will do anything and return:`**tell application "AppleScript Editor"
    display dialog "Sleep, Restart, or Shutdown?" buttons {"Sleep", "Restart", "Shutdown"} with title "What do you want to do?"
        --> {button returned:"Sleep"}
    display dialog "Exit All and Sleep or Just Sleep?" buttons {"Exit All", "Just Sleep"}
        --> {button returned:"Just Sleep"}
end tell**`

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: BTW: AppleScript-Editor has "code snippets". CTRL-Click into a script to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way it should work:

```
set question to display dialog "Sleep, Restart, or Shutdown?" buttons {"Sleep", "Restart", "Shutdown"} with title "What do you want to do?"
set answer to button returned of question

if answer is equal to "Restart" then
    tell application "Finder" to restart
end if

if answer is equal to "Shutdown" then
    tell application "Finder" to shut down
end if

if answer is equal to "Sleep" then

    set question2 to display dialog "Exit All and Sleep or Just Sleep?" buttons {"Exit All", "Just Sleep"}
    set answer2 to button returned of question2

    if answer2 is equal to "Exit All" then
        tell application "Finder" to run application "/Users/kjoesting/Desktop/Exit All and sleep.app"
    else if answer2 is equal to "Just Sleep" then
        tell application "Finder" to sleep
    end if

end if
```

---

Here is another version. I commented the actions and added log statements instead.
That way one can test the whole thing and see how it works without restarting etc. Un-comment the relevant lines and remove the log statements to get it work in real life:

```
display dialog "Sleep, Restart, or Shutdown?" buttons {"Sleep", "Restart", "Shutdown"} default button 1 with title "What do you want to do?"
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result

if the button_pressed is "Sleep" then
    -- action for 1st button goes here
    log "Sleep"

    display dialog "Exit All and Sleep or Just Sleep?" buttons {"Exit All", "Just Sleep"} default button 2
    set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
    if the button_pressed is equal to "Exit All" then
        --tell application "Finder" to run application "/Users/kjoesting/Desktop/Exit All and sleep.app"
        log "Exit All"

    else if button_pressed is equal to "Just Sleep" then
        -- tell application "Finder" to sleep
        log "Just Sleep"
    end if


else if the button_pressed is "Restart" then
    -- action for 2nd button goes here
    log "Restart"
    --tell application "Finder" to restart

else
    -- action for 3rd button goes here (Shutdown)
    log "Shut Down"
    --tell application "Finder" to shut down

end if
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both worked perfectly! I have alot to learn about it but I am enjoying the experience in working with it.

Comment: Cool, txs for the feedback. Here is the "Introduction to AppleScript Language Guide": http://developer.apple.com/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/index.html